# Mock return fails with MockMvc on Junit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking

Is it possible in a Junit test to make a post request and use BDDMockito.given () to set the return of a Service used by the method that responds to the RestController post? If it is possible, how to do it?

I'm trying to set the return of the Service and in the RestController method the Service returns null and the test fails.

These are the codes:

Test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SecurityBeanOverrideConfiguration.class, AccountApp.class})
public class UserSystemResourceIntTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserSystemService userSystemServiceMock;

    private MockMvc restUserSystemMockMvc;

    private UserSystem userSystem;

    public static UserSystem createEntity(EntityManager em) {
        UserSystem userSystem = new UserSystem()
            .name(DEFAULT_NAME)
            .email(DEFAULT_EMAIL)
            .phone(DEFAULT_PHONE)
            .documentCode(DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_CODE)
            .documentType(DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_TYPE)
            .gender(DEFAULT_GENDER)
            .createdOn(null)
            .updateOn(null)
            .active(null)
            .userId(null);

        return userSystem;
    }

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
        userSystem = createEntity(em);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createUserSystem() throws Exception {
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = userSystemRepository.findAll().size();

        // Create the UserSystem
        UserSystemDTO userSystemDTO = userSystemMapper.toDto(userSystem);

        userSystemDTO.setLangKey(DEFAULT_LANG_KEY);

        given(userSystemServiceMock.newAccount(userSystemDTO)).willReturn(createNewUserSystemDTO());


        restUserSystemMockMvc.perform(post("/api/user-systems")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(userSystemDTO)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated()); // FAIL BECAUSE RETURN STATUS 500

        // Validate the UserSystem in the database
        List<UserSystem> userSystemList = userSystemRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(userSystemList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate + 1);
        UserSystem testUserSystem = userSystemList.get(userSystemList.size() - 1);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.getName()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_NAME);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.getEmail()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_EMAIL);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.getPhone()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_PHONE);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.getDocumentCode()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_CODE);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.getDocumentType()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_TYPE);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.getGender()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_GENDER);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.getCreatedOn()).isNotNull(); //isEqualTo(DEFAULT_CREATED_ON);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.getUpdateOn()).isNull(); // EqualTo(DEFAULT_UPDATE_ON);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.isActive()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_ACTIVE);
        assertThat(testUserSystem.getUserId()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_USER_ID);

        // Validate the UserSystem in Elasticsearch
        verify(mockUserSystemSearchRepository, times(1)).save(testUserSystem);
    }

    private static UserSystemDTO createNewUserSystemDTO() {
        UserSystemDTO newUserSystemDTO = new UserSystemDTO(
                DEFAULT_USER_ID, DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_EMAIL, 
                DEFAULT_PASSWORD, DEFAULT_PHONE, DEFAULT_PHONE, 
                DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_TYPE, DEFAULT_GENDER, DEFAULT_LANG_KEY, 
                null, null, null, null);

        return newUserSystemDTO;

    }

}
```

RestController:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserSystemResource {

    private final UserSystemService userSystemService;

    private final UserSystemQueryService userSystemQueryService;

    public UserSystemResource(UserSystemService userSystemService, UserSystemQueryService userSystemQueryService) {
        this.userSystemService = userSystemService;
        this.userSystemQueryService = userSystemQueryService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/user-systems")
    public ResponseEntity<UserSystemDTO> createUserSystem(@Valid @RequestBody UserSystemDTO userSystemDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save UserSystem : {}", userSystemDTO);
        if (userSystemDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new userSystem cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        UserSystemDTO result = userSystemService.newAccount(userSystemDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/user-systems/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

}
```

Console error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.comp.account.web.rest.UserSystemResource.createUserSystem(UserSystemResource.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Result test error:

```
createUserSystem(com.comp.account.web.rest.UserSystemResourceIntTest)  Time elapsed: 205.661 s  <<< FAILURE!
    ava.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<500>
```

Comment: What is UserSystemResource.java:60 or what is `null` in this line?

Comment: This error occurs when the method tested calls the given() method seted, I do not understand why this happens because the tested method receives the object sent in post().

Comment: `UserSystemResource` does not even have 60 lines of code. Other classes necessary to compile + run this tests are missing. Actually, there are not full classes: no package names, no imports. Nobody can read anything from your error logs like this. I suggest you edit your question into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).